# Необходимо список номеров "прогнать" так чтобы на выходе получить их Телеграмм id

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot, telethon

Проблема заключается в следующем:
есть база клиентов (номер, имя и др.), я подключил ее к Телеграм боту, все работает отлично. Но как все понимают им необходимо в первый раз «поделиться номером» , я хочу избежать этого тем самым упростив клиенту жизнь. Хочу сам прогнать все номера автоматически.

Я все номера загнал в список

```
numbers = [79999999999,78888888888,…]
```

Затем ответом на какую либо команду циклом отправляю его как контакт себе же

```
for num in numbers:
    bot.send_contact(message.chat.id, num, "None")
```

Ну а дальше планирую просто все переслать ему же где он будет выбирать user_id и phone_number и заносить это в базу данных

Но тут проблема что он отправит 10 контактов и выкидывает

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 429. Description: Too Many Requests: retry after 250
```

Подскажите как с этим справится или возможно имеется уже готовый метод для обработки номера телефона и выдачи его user_id без отправки contact?

Comment: Сделай try/except где и при ошибке сделай asyncio.sleep(10)

Comment: @oleksandrigo я рассматривал такой вариант, но после отправки 10 контактов меня банят почти на 23 часа. Свою базу из 1000 клиентов я буду забивать больше месяца

Comment: Тогда пробуй при каждой отправке делать слип на эти самые секунды